# How to enable Keyboard navigation between full-screen images in ant design images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: ant design full screen images]

How to add keyboard navigation to this ant design full screen images as of now it is accessible only through click of pointer

Comment: Can you provide any code you have?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/image/#header - multiple image preview

Comment: it's not implemented https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/29323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component adds a bit of bloat and I really can't see a callback for after it loads a preview. However, that being said... This code does what you want. It's pretty fragile, and might break on updates of the module.

***Update***: Because I felt like I was taking something away with this answer, I fixed it now so all arrows are in sync with keyboard actions.

****Final Update*** I fixed an issue where having more than one gallery would break things. Should be perfect now.

Here's a [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-image-preview-antd4161-forked-5y58b)

```js
// Must be assigned to an onClick event
function onClickImage(e, parentContainer = null) {
  let currentImgSRC;
  if (e.currentTarget) {
    currentImgSRC = e.currentTarget.querySelector("img").src;
    // Keep track of our parent container, as not to include other containers
    parentContainer = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
  } else {
    currentImgSRC = e;
  }
  
  let PreviewWrapDoms = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ant-image-preview-wrap"
  );
  let ImgPreviewBodyDom = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ant-image-preview-body"
  )[0];
  // I don't see any kind of callback accessible for when the target
  // gets rendered, so we simply wait until the time is right.
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Previous viewers aren't self clearing, so I added that in.
    // Otherwise this breaks with multiple galleries
    if (typeof ImgPreviewBodyDom === "undefined" || PreviewWrapDoms.length > 1 ) {
      for (let WrapIndex = 0; WrapIndex < PreviewWrapDoms.length; WrapIndex++) {
        if ( window.getComputedStyle(PreviewWrapDoms[WrapIndex]).display === "none") {
          PreviewWrapDoms[WrapIndex].parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
      }
      onClickImage(currentImgSRC, parentContainer);
      return;
    }

    let ImgPreviewDom = ImgPreviewBodyDom.getElementsByClassName(
      "ant-image-preview-img"
    )[0];
    let LeftArrowDom = ImgPreviewBodyDom.getElementsByClassName(
      "ant-image-preview-switch-left"
    )[0];
    let RightArrowDom = ImgPreviewBodyDom.getElementsByClassName(
      "ant-image-preview-switch-right"
    )[0];
    // Assigning event listeners for the left and right arrows.
    if (LeftArrowDom.getAttribute("listener") !== "true")
      LeftArrowDom.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClickImage(
          LeftArrowDom.getAttribute("data-img-prev"),
          parentContainer
        );
      });
    LeftArrowDom.setAttribute("listener", "true");
    // Now the right arrow
    if (RightArrowDom.getAttribute("listener") !== "true")
      RightArrowDom.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClickImage(
          LeftArrowDom.getAttribute("data-img-next"),
          parentContainer
        );
      });
    RightArrowDom.setAttribute("listener", "true");

    // Set these previous and next img sources to the current
    // for the edge cases that may be there is no next or previous
    let previousImgSRC = currentImgSRC;
    let nextImgSRC = currentImgSRC;
    let ImgDoms = parentContainer.getElementsByClassName("ant-image-img");

    // Cycle through the dom in the container to see which we are
    for (let ImgDomIndex = 0; ImgDomIndex < ImgDoms.length; ImgDomIndex++) {
      if (currentImgSRC === ImgDoms[ImgDomIndex].src) {
        if (ImgDomIndex > 0) { //If greater than zero, we know there's a previous
          previousImgSRC = ImgDoms[ImgDomIndex - 1].src;
          LeftArrowDom.setAttribute("data-img-prev", previousImgSRC);
          LeftArrowDom.classList.remove(
            "ant-image-preview-switch-left-disabled"
          );
        } else {
          LeftArrowDom.classList.add("ant-image-preview-switch-left-disabled");
        }
        if (ImgDomIndex + 1 < ImgDoms.length) { // if the next index doesn't exist, no next
          nextImgSRC = ImgDoms[ImgDomIndex + 1].src;
          LeftArrowDom.setAttribute("data-img-next", nextImgSRC);
          RightArrowDom.classList.remove(
            "ant-image-preview-switch-right-disabled"
          );
        } else {
          RightArrowDom.classList.add(
            "ant-image-preview-switch-right-disabled"
          );
        }
        // Once we know where we are in the index, we can set the preview
        // Image source to our desired result.
        ImgPreviewDom.src = currentImgSRC;

        // We break here because once we know our index, we don't need more
        break;
      }
    }

    // checks for keydown events on the dom.
    this.onkeydown = (e) => {
      e = e || window.event;

      switch (e.keyCode) {
        // we use recursion here to keep everything contained nicely.
        case 37:
          onClickImage(previousImgSRC, parentContainer);
          break;
        case 39:
          onClickImage(nextImgSRC, parentContainer);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };
  }, 500);
}
```

Here's the code you'll need for an Image preview group:

```js
    <Image.PreviewGroup>
      <Image
        onClick={onClickImage}
        width={200}
        src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/KDpgvguMpGfqaHPjicRK.svg"
      />
      <Image
        onClick={onClickImage}
        width={200}
        src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/antfincdn/aPkFc8Sj7n/method-draw-image.svg"
      />
    </Image.PreviewGroup>
```

Comment: i get this error Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of null on first click itself

Comment: I tested this on Mac and Windows in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari and Edge. I also tested Android and IPhone, everything was green. I'll need to know what browser you're using to help.

Comment: I am  using chrome

Comment: Not sure what to say, you can run the test yourself here: https://www.browserling.com/

Comment: I will go through the code once again and i really appreciate your effort

Comment: Nontheless, it passes all the tests - so I'd really appreciate you accepting the answer. I do not see an easier way of implementing what you're asking and that's what this answer aimed to accomplish: give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

**This Link can help you in similar way actually this is a image gallery that uses onclick event to open images you can use similar concept to get response.**

https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-create-a-tab-image-gallery-html-css-and-javascript/

Comment: it is not at all useful

Comment: I'm going to be *really* honest. I took a solid crack at trying to solve this but the addon you want to use adds **a lot** of bloat to an otherwise simple thing to code. I'd recommend this solution if you're not willing to accept the whims of the developers for ant and what they decide to implement.